# Upload an image blob from Ajax to Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to to upload an image to Django using Ajax.

Ajax code:

```
function sendImage() {
    console.log(blob);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', blob);
    var tet = $.ajax({
        url: '/login/photoverify/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        async: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.driverBeacon);
            document.getElementById('username').setAttribute('value', response.username);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }).responseText;
}
```

Django Code:

```
def imageVerify(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        log.info('Inside imageVerify')
        myform = forms.Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        log.info("Done loading form")
        if myform.is_valid():
            log.info(myform.cleaned_data)
            file = myform.cleaned_data['image']
```

But `myform.cleaned_data` is empty. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't passed `request.FILES` to the form instantiation.

```
myform = forms.Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

You might also need to set `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` in the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: If I change both contentType and form instantiation the code hangs on line myform = forms.Form(request.POST, request.FILES). If I dont change content type the form coming is empty

Comment: What do you mean, it hangs? Do you get any kind of error?

Comment: INFO:usermanagement.user: exit login view and execution time 0.0342240333557  (2018-01-05 08:25:34; user.py:71)
INFO:usermanagement.user: Inside imageVerify (2018-01-05 08:25:41; user.py:346)

Then program hangs. Does not print anything.

Comment: Thanks. This saved me from a stupid bug. Also, I recommend `contentType: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
 def imageVerify(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    log.info('Inside imageVerify')
    myform = forms.Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    log.info("got Myform")
    file = myform.files['image']
```